# Validation while rendering multiple partial views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have multiple views/models that are being looped into the main view. I load them via @Html.Partial()...These views/models are basically form elements with certain properties...Unfortunately I soon found out that only the first of each type of view/model is validated. I tried moving the fields around and only the first of each kind would validate.

My partial views look something like this:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.dropdownVal,Model.SelectItems,new { id=Model.FieldID, Name = Model.FieldID })
```

I looked at the HTML rendered, and it seems that the validation tags like "data-val" are not applied...

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following at the top of your partials to trick ASP.NET MVC into thinking that the helpers are used inside a form and generate the proper data-val attributes:

```
@{
    this.ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
```

Basically the `Html.*` helpers are generating `data-val` clients side validation attributes only if they are placed inside an `Html.BeginForm`. Except that in your case I guess that this `Html.BeginForm` is in your parent view and not inside the partial, so the `@Html.DropDownListFor` doesn't emit any validation attributes. By setting the current `FormContext` to a new instance in the partial as shown previously, the helper will generate the proper client side validation attributes on the corresponding input field.